Stopwords problem in text data preprocessing in Python
I want to do topic modeling in Python. For this reason, I used my own stop word list, a stop word list I found on GitHub, and nltk's stop word list to clean the stopwords. However, when I examined the results, I saw that the words I had previously specified as stopwords were not removed and were placed inside the topics. I have given the codes I used for data preprocessing below. These codes work without any errors. I have also added a topic I saw as an example. I cannot understand why the stopwords are not completely cleaned. I would be very happy if you could help me.

import pandas as pd
import nltk
import spacy
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
import requests


nltk.download('punkt')
nltk.download('stopwords')
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')



# GitHub stopwords
url = "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/rg089/35e00abf8941d72d419224cfd5b5925d/raw/12d899b70156fd0041fa9778d657330b024b959c/stopwords.txt"
github_stopwords = set(requests.get(url).text.splitlines())

# my stopwords 
with open('/content/s.txt') as f:
    my_stopwords = set(line.strip() for line in f)

# NLTK stopwords 
nltk_stopwords = set(stopwords.words('english'))

# All stopwords 
all_stopwords = nltk_stopwords.union(github_stopwords, my_stopwords)

# clean function
def preprocess_text(text):
    # 1. Lower
    text = text.lower()
    
    # 2. Tokenization 
    words = word_tokenize(text)
    
    # 3. keep alphanumeric words
    words = [word for word in words if word.isalpha() and word not in all_stopwords]
  
    print(f"remaining words:{words}")
    
     # 4. Stopwords filter
    filtered_words = [word for word in words if word not in all_stopwords]

    # 5. Lemmatization (spaCy used)
    doc = nlp(" ".join( filtered_words))
    lemmatized_words = [token.lemma_ for token in doc]

    print(f"Lemmatized text: {' '.join(lemmatized_words)}\n")
    
    # Return sanitized text
    return " ".join(lemmatized_words)

output:
 For example, a few words in this topic (challenge, theoretical)

 Topic 25: challenge, framework, theoretical, provide, offer 


why you are filtering your stopwords twice .?
redundancy can be simplified
text = text.lower()
words = [word for word in word_tokenize(text) if word.isalpha() and word not in all_stopwords]

Suggestions
You can check your stoplist to ensure it contains only lowercase words. The issue may also arise from the arguments you pass into the topic modeling model.
Because pre-processing code works fine for me (even though there are two identical stopwords removal steps):
import pandas as pd
import nltk
import spacy
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
import requests


nltk.download('punkt')
nltk.download('stopwords')
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')



# GitHub stopwords
url = "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/rg089/35e00abf8941d72d419224cfd5b5925d/raw/12d899b70156fd0041fa9778d657330b024b959c/stopwords.txt"
github_stopwords = set(requests.get(url).text.splitlines())

my_stopwords={ "challenge", "theoretical"}
# NLTK stopwords 
nltk_stopwords = set(stopwords.words('english'))

# All stopwords 
all_stopwords = nltk_stopwords.union(github_stopwords, my_stopwords)

# clean function
def preprocess_text(text):
    # 1. Lower
    text = text.lower()
    
    # 2. Tokenization 
    words = word_tokenize(text)
    
    # 3. keep alphanumeric words
    words = [word for word in words if word.isalpha() and word not in all_stopwords]
  
    print(f"remaining words:{words}")
    
     # 4. Stopwords filter
    filtered_words = [word for word in words if word not in all_stopwords]

    # 5. Lemmatization (spaCy used)
    doc = nlp(" ".join( filtered_words))
    lemmatized_words = [token.lemma_ for token in doc]

    print(f"Lemmatized text: {' '.join(lemmatized_words)}\n")
    
    # Return sanitized text
    return " ".join(lemmatized_words)

test_sentence = "This is a theoretical challenge to offer some insights and provide a useful framework."

preprocessed_test = preprocess_text(test_sentence)
print(preprocessed_test)

Output:
offer insight provide framework


When I check the Lemmatized words before running the topical modeling algorithm, I see that the word "challenge" is not removed.
"Example: Lemmatized text: deployment identification systematic manner focus seek identify prioritize barrier base expert challenge"
